# JPMS; trying to use a class from a dependecy module as mainClass fails in maven build

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system, maven-jar-plugin

I have a Java maven project that has dependencies to other libraries. One of these dependecies has a Main class that can be used as < mainClass > in my **maven-jar-plugin** so I don't have have to create a Main class for my jar.
Everything worked fine until I decided to move them to JPMS (Java Platform Module System)

I turned both my project (client module) and that dependency into java module and made sure all "exports" and "requires" are correct in module-info.java files.

but when I try to do mvn clean install I get the error during JAR creation and using -X I see this error that

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Could not create modular JAR file. The JDK jar tool exited with 1
```

looking at the log the only culprit I can see is this message about the package that contains the Main class :

```
Package a.b.c.d missing from ModulePackages class file attribute
```

Now if I create a Main class in my client module and use it as < mainClass > for **maven-jar-plugin** configuration, everything works.

I would like to know if this a limitation enforced by JPMS or something is missing in my module-info.javs files
Also I didn't fully understoo the notion of "ModulePackages class file attribute". Where this attribute should be defined?

---

Another point that might shed more light is that, in the Main class that I created in my client module I can call the Main class of the other module without any problem.
So the only problem is that I can not use that other Main class as the < mainClass > of my **maven-jar-plugin** config.
could this be a limitation that the Main class of a module jar must be one of its own classes ? or this is a limitation maven jar plugin?

Comment: Does the package  `a.b.c.d` really exist and have you made use of it in `module-info.java` with any directive? It would be much better if you could share the details to reproduce this issue. Do mention the versions of Maven and the jar plugin in use too.

Comment: Thank, for you comment. Yes, there is a "exports a.b.c.d" in the module-info.java of the other project.
I can't share the code, it is a bit too large and not owned by me.